# How to erase GRUB when I already use another bootloader?

Tags: grub, macbook

I've just added an elementary OS install on my already dual-booting Macbook. It uses rEFIt for switching OS from OSX to Win7 or Linux. But when I switch to elementary OS (via rEFIt), i'm then greeted with a GRUB screen asking once more to select which system I want to boot from.

How can I suppress GRUB (which is installed on the main Linux partition) and rely solely on rEFIt for switching OS ?

Comment: OMG! you actually installed windows on a macbook?!
That's blasfemy! hahaha

Comment: Use rEFInd instead of rEFIt

Answer (score 1):

Before literally removing GRUB from your elementaryOS, consider settings its timeout to 0 (so you won't see it, but it's still there). To do it, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the lines that begin with `GRUB_HIDDEN` and put a `#` in front of each one. Also do it with the `GRUB_DEFAULT` line. Now change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` line so it looks like `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`. Hit Ctrl+O and then ENTER to save the file and hit Ctrl+X to exit. Run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You have been warned. Now I'll teach you how to actually remove GRUB from your partition's boot section. In a terminal, run:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/home/user/mbr.img bs=446 count=1
```

To make a backup of GRUB in your home folder, then

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=446 count=1
```

To remove it.

If you want to recover GRUB, just run

```
sudo dd if=/home/user/mbr.img of=/dev/sdx bs=446 count=1
```

(!!!) Don't forget to replace `sdx` with your partition name and `user` with yout username!

I hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot Eduardo ! I resorted to set the timeout to 0 as you suggested and it's doing the trick. But I'm keeping the complete removal method you gave for later, when i'm better acquainted with Linux. :)